# UIBezierPath with multiple color?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibezierpath

I am working on project in which i am using `UIBezierPath` for drawing. My problem is that when i change the color of the path, whole `UIBezierPath` color changes. I want to ask is it possible to change the color of `UIBezierPath` with multiple lines.

Regards

Comment: so you want each line in the path to have a different color?

Comment: I want something like I choose a color form UI and rest of the future drawing changes to respective color until i change the other color, and the previously drawing will keep in same color as they were drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one single UIBezier path you can't AFAIK

You can do something like this

///// Add this in drawRect

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in pathArray) {
    UIBezierPath *_path = [dic valueForKey:@"path"];
    [[dic valueForKey:@"fColor"] setFill]; 
    [[dic valueForKey:@"sColor"] setStroke];
    [_path stroke]; 
  }
```

Populating array in touch events

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.currentPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    self.currentPath.lineWidth=5;
    self.currentPath.miterLimit=-10;
    self.currentPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    self.currentPath.flatness = 0.0;


    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.currentPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setObject:currentfColor forKey:@"fColor"];
    [dic setObject:currentsColor forKey:@"sColor"];
    [dic setObject:self.currentPath forKey:@"path"];
    [pathArray addObject:dic];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self.currentPath addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

**PS: This is just an example. I havent checked this code, yet it should work may be some alteration needed.**

Comment: its again setting all the path to the current selected color,

Comment: You will have to set color in dictionary in touches began as shown, pls find code in edits

Comment: can you give me a working example of it, code snippet is not working as expected, thanks